# bootstrap-select identify button in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

i'm trying to display update button in for loop form with bootstrap-selectpicker.

i have a for loop, inside each loop i have a form with more than one select with selectpicker and a button (setted in display: none) to save the value of the all select in this form.

so at the end i will have n form and for each form x select and a button (setted in display: none) to update the value for the form.

with this code from selectpicker documentation

```
<script>
    $('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
        $('.button_update').show();
    });
</script>
```

i can show all update button, but i want to show only the update button inside the form where i change the value in the select.

```
START of LOOP

<form id="skill_form">
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="skill_1" id="skill_1"
                class="selectpicker form-control skill_select show-tick"
                data-live-search="true"
                data-size="10"
                data-width="fit"
                title="name">
            <option value="value">name</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="skill_2" id="skill_2"
                class="selectpicker form-control skill_select show-tick"
                data-live-search="true"
                data-size="10"
                data-width="fit"
                title="name">
            <option value="value">name</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin:0; display:none;">
    <!-- Update skills -->
    <div class="col-12" style="padding: 0; text-align: center;">
        <button type="submit"
                form="skill_form"
                class="btn btn-info button_update"
                style="display: none; font-size: 1em;">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

END OF LOOP

<script>
    $('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
        $('.button_update').show();
    });
</script>
```

i tried to passing parameter but i don't know how and i can't put the jquery inside the loop passing the id of element that i looping.

Someone can help?

Comment: the goal is unclear. You have several select elements inside a form each one having an id (and name) ending with a progressive number. Then you have a change event handler for all those select elements. And you have one submit button inside the form. First of all the change event will never fire for those select because there's only one option inside. Then I may add that you didn't include all the required assets (bootstrap css/js, jquery, popper, bootstrap-select)

Comment: But there's one button in your code and it's unclear how you want to discern which one to show since there's one only anyway

Comment: ok a tried to explain better my problem, it is understable?

Comment: it's hard to understand why you have multiple forms and why you have multiple select elements in each form.. and how the whole game is supposed to work. Anyway I just gave everything for granted without touching what's seemed to be expected and blindly multiplied the forms for the sake of showing how a single select change event handler can determine how to show the button on the corresponding parent form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not perfectly sure to correctly address the problem.

Anyway here you have a demo that on document ready will create a number of forms (5 in this case) cloning a given template `#skill_form` having one select and one button inside a form. All the elements inside the template have no id so when it will be cloned to be appended to the document, the unique id requirement won't be violated.

After the forms will be appended, the select elements will be initialized with `.selectpicker()` and a change event handler will be added to all of them.

Such handler will rely on the event value (coming from `e`) to determine which element fired the event and what's its parent form that needs its own submit button to be showed.

I simplified the scenario using one select only per form and cloning them all the same just for the sake of having a demo with multiple form instances.

Each one might be populated with a different `action` or better differentiated in their structure.

Since the select elements showed had only one option, I added an empty option to have the chance for the `change` event to trigger somehow.

```js
//creates n forms inside the target #formContainer (cloning the template #skill_form)
function createForms(n){
  const templateForm = document.getElementById('skill_form');  
  const formContainer = document.getElementById('formContainer');
  for(let i=1; i<=n; i++){    
    const newForm = templateForm.content.cloneNode(true);    
    formContainer.appendChild(newForm);    
  }
}

//on document ready
$(document).ready(()=>{
  
  //create the forms (5)
  createForms(5);

  //inits the .selectpicker(s)
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  
  //add change event handlers to all selects
  $('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function(e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
    //this is the element firing the change event
    const changedSelect = e.target;
    console.log(changedSelect);  
    //this is the parent form relative to the select firing the event
    const parentForm = changedSelect.closest('form');
    console.log(parentForm);    
    //show the child button update
    $(parentForm.querySelector('.button_update')).show();
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  border: solid 1px darkgray;
  margin: 1rem 1rem;
  padding: 1rem
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.0 required assets -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- bootstrap-select required assets -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div id="formContainer"></div>

<template id="skill_form">
  <form>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select
          name="skill"          
          class="selectpicker form-control skill_select show-tick"
          data-live-search="true"
          data-size="10"
          data-width="fit"
          title="name">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="value">name</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="row" style="margin:0;">
      <!-- Update skills -->
      <div class="col-12" style="padding: 0; text-align: center;">
        <button
          type="submit"          
          class="btn btn-info button_update"
          style="display: none; font-size: 1em;">Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it work perefctly.
i'm sorry for my bad explanation, but i'm the only one developer the company where i work, and i haven't so much experience in fronted develop